# what happens if delegate doesnot exist anymore?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, crash, viewdidload

I came around a interesting issue while working on my app. Imagine the scenerio where

- There exist one object, Lets call it A.
- A, then creates an object(B) of some delegation based class, say NSURLConnection.
- A assigned itself as delegate of B, provided A has implemented all the  required delegate methods.
- A asks B to start its processing. In our example i.e. fetching data from some server.
- As soon as B finished fetching data, it will call some specified method of A.

In the last step, suppose while calling the methods of A, B finds that the A object doesnt exist anymore. Then what happens???

I'm not sure but does it cause crash?

If yes, then please suggest me how to avoid the situation.

In my case I assigned the viewcontroller as delegate of some object, say X in `viewDidLoad` method. There are cases when viewcontroller get destroyed before X calls the delegate methods defined in the viewcontroller.

- If assigning X's delegate to nil solves the problem. Then where
  should i do that.

In short, which method is called only once while unloading phase of view controller likewise
`viewDidLoad` in its loading phase.

Comment: As a note, `NSURLConnection` *does* retain its delegate.

Comment: @Guillaume yes you were right. Its all about retaining the delegate. So better if we set the delegate to nil.

Comment: and yes definitelty it causes crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking against a valid delegate object should be sufficient enough.

```
if (delegate)
   [delegate method];
```

Comment: specifically speaking about the NSURLConnection class, did you mean it will not look for the viewcontroller or viewcontroller's " - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection" method, if view controller doesn't exist any more?

Comment: If the delegate is deallocated , then "delegate" will point to some garbage pointer..
I'd (and the MVC design pattern would) prefer using notifications for this kind of flow.

Answer (score 1):

You should not reach a situation where one object holds a reference to another object which may be deallocated somewhere else without the owner object being notified.

Either when deallocating object `A` notify object `B` (by making member `a` `nill` in object B for example) or modify your design/flow to never allow `A` to be deallocated before `B` finishes (e.g. retain `A` when assigning as a delegate in `B` if possible)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this kind of communication between classes (where class A could be deallocated at any time) is listening to **`NSNotifications`**.
As you stated , using **weak(assign)** delegates is dangerous and requires extra thought.
Using **strong** delegates could as well create a memory bloat (why should we retain a view controller so long after popping it from the view anyway?).

For more on NSNotificationCenter and notifications , you can find a lot of info in the SDK docs.. for specific questions, you know where to ask..